# Replace "CopyFileFromGuestToHost" and "runProgramInGuest" by xcopy and simple execution, what can I expect

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, virtual-machine, windows-vista

My company is working with virtual machines. Those are managed, using a central host who connects to different virtual machines (using ESX virtual machines handling technology).

One of those virtual machines centralises all operations, and by using `runProgramInGuest` and `CopyFileFromGuestToHost`, everything is handled.

This system is causing quite some issues, mostly due to the instability of the mentioned commands `runProgramInGuest` and especially `CopyFileFromGuestToHost`, and I would like to solve this in a simple matter:

My idea is to put all those hosts in a normal network, giving every virtual machine a network name (like pc001, pc002, ...), and then use commands like `xcopy /F \\pc001\<dir>\<filename> .` instead of `CopyFileFromGuestToHost` and a simple execution `\\pc002\<dir>\<bathfile>.bat` instead of `runProgramInGuest`.

My question is: what needs to be done for this and which problems might I expect? As an example, one the things I don't know how to handle, is the restarting of a guest and the application of a snapshot (in order to get the machine back in its original state). Can somebody help me out here?

For your information: all machines are Windows based: Windows-7, Windows-Vista and Windows-10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason why most of the operations have to change if you do this. You can still use the vSphere client to be able to do all operations on the VMs such as reboot, shutdown, rollback to snapshot or others. You'll also be able to add them to VMWare Workstation if you have the latest version. All you have to do is add the ESX host as a remote server.

The fact that each VM will have it's own network name should only make things more simple. The one thing you'll have to think about is that your users will need to be authorized to these VM's to be able to do the copy/run operations as it seems you only had one machine who was centralized that did this before.

This will also reduce your latency as you won't be going though an RDP machine before doing the operations.

Overall, unless I didn't understand something in your current setup, this would be a recommended move for scalability of your virtual network.