# Stability of `start /wait` in batchfiles

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-vista, batch-file

This question is related to [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/1149393/replace-copyfilefromguesttohost-and-runprograminguest-by-xcopy-and-simple-ex)
The previous question was about the problem, this one about a possible solution.

I'm working with a group of virtual machines, using "runProgramInGuest", running programs, who are calling subprograms, ...

I'd like to replace this by such execution scheme:

```
start /wait CMD_1
  start /wait CMD_1.1
  start /wait CMD_1.2
    start /wait CMD_1.2.1
    start /wait CMD_1.2.2
start /wait CMD_2
```

The scheme means that CMD_1.bat looks like:

```
  start /wait CMD_1.1.bat
  start /wait CMD_1.2.bat
```

CMD_1.2.bat looks like:

```
  start /wait CMD_1.2.1.bat
  start /wait CMD_1.2.2.bat
```

...

It is crucial that one (sub)command only starts once the previous one has been finished (which is the exact reason I'm using the ´/wait´ parameter).

I will be working with virtual Windows-7, Windows-Vista and Windows-10 machines, and I would like to know if the mentioned `start /wait` is known as a reliable command for this purpose (from personal experience, I confirm that the virtual software command `runProgramInGuest` is not reliable).

Comment: If all the CMD_x.y.z you refer to are batches - is there a reason not to use `call CMD` ?

Comment: I don't know the difference between `start /wait` and `call`. I thought by choosing `start /wait`, I've chosen the best way to start a task and to wait for it to finish. Do you disagree?